# How to make a post request with node using chai in mocha and mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mocha.js, chai

1. How to make a POST request with node using chai in mocha and mongoDB.
   I have a test file that contains both my get request and post request. I the code below equals my get request that passed the 1 test I set it up for, but I'm having trouble creating my post request and I do not understand what I am supposed to do. GET request:

   ```
   const chai = require('chai');
   const expect = chai.expect;
   const chaiHttp = require('chai-http')

   chai.use(chaiHttp)

   describe('site', () => {       // Describe what you are testing
       it('Should have home page', (done) => { // Describe 
           // In this case we test that the home page loads
           chai.request('localhost:3000')
           chai.get('/')
           chai.end((err, res) => {
               if (err) {
                   done(err)
               }
               res.status.should.be.equal(200)
               done()   // Call done if the test completed successfully.
           })
       })
   })
   ```

---

2. This is my post/create route so far:
3. The pseudocode of this request is:
4. // How many posts are there now?
5. // Make a request to create another
6. // Check that the database has one more post in it
7. // Check that the response is a successful
8. POST Request:

   ```
   const chai = require('chai')
   const chaiHttp = require('chai-http')
   const should = chai.should()
   chai.use(chaiHttp)
   const Post = require('../models/post');

   describe('Posts', function() {
       this.timeout(10000);
       let countr;

       it('should create with valid attributes at POST /posts', function(done) {
           // test code
           Post.find({}).then(function(error, posts) {
               countr = posts.count;

               let head = {
                   title: "post title", 
                   url: "https://www.google.com", 
                   summary: "post summary"
               }
               chai.request('localhost:3000')
               chai.post('/posts').send(head)
               chai.end(function(error, res) {
                   //console.log('success')
               })
           }).catch(function(error) {
               done(error)
           })
       });
   })
   ```
9. Any pointers on what I am doing wrong are appreciated. My OUTPUT for this error is:

1) Posts
       should return a new post at POST /posts:
     Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; ifreturning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reddit_clone@1.0.0 test: `mocha`

Comment: *”I’m having trouble”* - we’ll what trouble are you having exactly? You don’t appear to do anything with the `err` param from the POST, would be a good place to start.

Comment: I modified my post request to a more updated version of what I have, still my test doesn't run successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test is timing out because the request is never sent.

Based on the [docs](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/) I’m not seeing anything that suggests you can perform a post by simply passing the data into the `post` function. There would need to be a lot of assumptions made by the library here e.g. serialization type, headers etc.

The correct way to perform a POST request with a JSON payload would be:

```
chai
  .request('http://localhost:3000')
  .post('/posts')
  .send(head)
  .end((err, res) => {
    ...
  });
```

Comment: Thank you James for the try, however, I still get the same error after modifying that line of code.

Comment: @StephanieGomez so does the `end` function get hit? Is there an error? Are you calling `done`?